# Convert a java list of data into a JSON array of array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, arraylist

Good morning, everyone. Hope you're well. Actually I'd like to convert a list with data into a JSON table of this form:

```
[[45.21406,5.74749,445,"2019-11-05T15:29:45Z"],
[45.21401,5.74752,470,"2019-11-05T15:29:46Z"],
[45.21397,5.74763,472,"2019-11-05T15:29:47Z"],
[45.21393,5.74789,471,"2019-11-05T15:29:48Z"],
[45.21389,5.74849,473,"2019-11-05T15:29:49Z"]
]
```

My code is the next :

```
    activity.longitude=result.getLastLocation().getLongitude();

    activity.latitude=result.getLastLocation().getLatitude();

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

    activity.dateFormated= formatter.format(new Date());

    activity.altitude=result.getLastLocation().getAltitude();

    activity.data.add(activity.longitude);
    activity.data.add(activity.latitude);
    activity.data.add(activity.dateFormated);
    activity.data.add(activity.altitude);
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a JSON library to make this easy and correct.  This is a simple one to get started with.

https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

Comment: Good suggestion, great library to get started, +1.

Comment: I'll also add the tricky part they don't document well, your java class (POJO) needs to have get/set for every field.

Answer (score 0):

so this can be done using a host of different libraries but one that could be particularly helpful is [Gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6). Unfortunately you have not posted your POJO that represented these values so it's difficult to help you further and give an example but this should help.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I don't understand  what's a POJO. I'm beginner and I don't know a lot about JSON. If you you mean the type of the the objects, longitude, altitude, altitude are double, and dateFormated is a String. If some one have an exemple of code it will help me so much because I don't know anything about the JSON format, i just would like to have a array of array in JSON

Comment: Yeah, so your first step in learning the skills necessary would be to look up JSON and what it is exactly. Then it would be a good idea to look up what are some API's, such as GSON, that make reading/writing JSON easier, and then implement it.